# How to calculate the partial derivatives of m and b using a cost function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, python

I've been diving into some beginner Calculus due to my interest in machine learning, mostly as a hobby. With that being said, I'm having some trouble understanding how the slope and y-intercept of a linear regression are derived based on an example in the Book, Essential Math for Data Science.

```
m = 0.0
b = 0.0

L = .002

iterations = 100_000

n = float(len(points))

for i in range(iterations):
    D_m = sum(2 * p.x * ((m * p.x + b) - p.y) for p in points)

    D_b = sum(2 * ((m * p.x + b) - p.y) for p in points)

    m -= L * D_m
    b -= L * D_b

print("y = {0}x + {1}".format(m, b))
```

From what I know of the power rule, if we have two variables we want to partial derivative of, we do each one separately, with the other a constant, which = 0.

```
f(x) = x^2 + y^3

d_x, wrt x = 2x + 0

d_y wrt y = 3y + 0
```

For the code above, why do we multiple by x twice in D_m and only once in D_b?

Comment: Hi, welcome on the forum, could you detail what are your $D$ values ?

Comment: https://bit.ly/2KF29Bd
D_m = 2 * p.x * (m * p.x + b) - p.y
D_b = 2 * (m * p.x + b) - p.y

Comment: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2017/readings/L02%20Linear%20Regression.pdf

This is helpful ,but I have the same question. I just want to know where "2 * p.x" (m * p.x + b) is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The cost function writes
$$\phi(m,b)
= \sum_n \left[ (b+mx_n)-y_n \right]^2
$$
The gradient wrt $m$ writes
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial m}
\doteq \phi_m
= 2 \sum_n x_n \left[ (b+mx_n)-y_n \right]
$$
Gradient descent to solve the linear regression problem implies the update
$$
m_{k+1}
= m_{k} - \eta \ \phi_m (m_{k})
$$
where $\eta$ is the learning rate.
I guess now you can clearly identify which part of the code these equations belong to.

Comment: Thank you. Why is Xn multiplied by the cost function though? I know this is the chain rule and the power rule, but I can't figure out where Xn is coming in the derivative wrt m

Comment: To compute the gradient, we need to use the chain rule. The $x_n$ comes from the term $mx_n$ during the differentiation.